# What is the relation between entropy and mass of black hole?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, black-holes, entropy, quantum-gravity

1. What is the relation between entropy and mass of black hole?
2. And what is the relation between symmetry of physics operation and entropy?For instance,measuring or doing measure on state of quantum system especially pure state of a system  has to lead to increase in entropy of the system,and the measuring is not symmetric operation,but it seems that the statement is tautologic,because that operations make processes symmetric,means nothing has been changed.

Comment: Your second question is very unclear to me. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @Danu, Yes,I know,and I have rephrased it,but I am not sure if it is clear to you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.
Hawking-Bekenstein entropy of a black hole is given by $S_{\text{BH}} = \frac{kAc^3}{4\hbar G}$ where $A$ is the area of the event horizon. Assuming a non-rotating black hole, there holds $r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$ for the Schwartzschild radius, and therefore $A=4\pi r_s^2=\frac{16\pi G^2M^2}{c^4}$, which results in
$$
S_{BH}=\frac{4kGM^2}{\hbar c}
$$

For rotating black holes, the calculation is basically the same, just your Schwartzschild radius and the geometry you use to calculate $A$ is a bit different.

Your second question is not perfectly clear. If you assume the microcanonical ensemble, your entropy is proportional to the logarithm of your partition function, therefore a symmetry of the system, resulting in a degeneracy of the energy states, will increase your entropy as there are more possibilities to realize one microcanonical state.

Comment: Thank you.Is the entropy of black hole is minimal among system with the same mass?Does this means mass is equivalent to entropy in the extremely simple case?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal"?

Comment: it's entropy is the smallest one among systems with the same amount of mass to it.But maybe this assertion is wrong,since I have just read a post about rotating black hole's entropy.

Comment: For a macroscopic system with given mass, as far as I know, there is no canonical way to assign an entropy to the system, therefore you can't compare it to the black hole entropy on a basic level.

Comment: ,thanks,but is it impossible to estimate then low bound of a macroscopic system with given mass?If the low bound of a macroscopic system with given mass equals to the entropy of black hole,the answer is positive,otherwise negative